# Button is not after starting timer

Tags: javascript, html

I am using setInterval() and clearInterval() methods for timer and stopping the timer respectively. I am using two buttons "start Timer" and "stop timer". when I click the "stop timer" button the time stops and after clicking "start timer" button it stops and after that when I click "stop timer" button again the time won't stop. Can you please help me in this?
here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="start"></p>
        <button onClick = "startTimer()">Start Timer </button>
        <button onClick = "stopTimer()"> Stop Timer </button>
        <script>
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
            function myTimer()
            {
                var time = new Date();
                var t = time.toLocaleTimeString();
                document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = t;
            }
            function startTimer()
            {
                setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
            }
            function stopTimer()
            {
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the interval to myVar variable in startTimer() function. Because of that stopTimer() doesn't clear the interval set by the startTimer() function..

For more safty you may clear the interval before setting it. Otherwise if the user clicks the start timer button more than once, then the timer stop button won't work anymore. Because a new interval is set without clearing the previous interval, the previous intervals which were not cleared will be running then...

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="start"></p>
        <button onClick = "startTimer()">Start Timer </button>
        <button onClick = "stopTimer()"> Stop Timer </button>
        <script>
            var myVar;
            startTimer();
            function myTimer()
            {
                var time = new Date();
                var t = time.toLocaleTimeString();
                document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = t;
            }
            function startTimer()
            {
                clearInterval(myVar);
                myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
            }
            function stopTimer()
            {
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function startTimer()
{
    myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="start"></p>
        <button onClick = "startTimer()">Start Timer </button>
        <button onClick = "stopTimer()"> Stop Timer </button>
        <script>
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
            function myTimer()
            {
                var time = new Date();
                var t = time.toLocaleTimeString();
                document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = t;
            }
            function startTimer()
            {
               myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
            }
            function stopTimer()
            {
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```